# How to pause the background music while recording audio in android

Tags: android

I am developing an audio record application in android. So if any background music is already playing in the device music player, that should be paused before it starts recording and the background music should resume whenever the recording is either stopped or paused. And the same should work while playing the recorded audio. Can anybody help me out to get through this scenario? Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 3):

get audioManager and check

```
audioManager.isMusicActive()
```

if true

```
private void toggleNativePlayer(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
    intent.putExtra("command", "togglepause");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and after you finish recording run this code again to start play musig again

Comment: Does not work anymore. Google is cutting down on such Broadcasts now.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop other applications from playing music, by requesting *AudioFocus*. When you are granted *AudioFocus*, other apps stop playing music and then you can play/record as per your needs.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
// Use the music stream.
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
// Request permanent focus.
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);


if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
// other app had stopped playing song now , so you can start recording.
}
```

But, there is only one AudioManager. So, Audio focus is assigned to each application that requests it **one by one.** This means that if another application requests audio focus, **your application will lose it**. You will be notified of the loss of audio focus through the onAudioFocusChange handler of the Audio Focus Change Listener (**afChangeListener**) you registered when requesting the audio focus.

```
 private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
      new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
              public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                         AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                switch (focusChange) {

                       case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                       //Lost focus. Stop recording
                       break;

                       case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                       //Gained AudioFocus. Start recording tasks
                       break;
                       default: break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, How can I resume the previous music?

Comment: Ok, this works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794274/9686461