# How to play or resume music of another music player from my code

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, resume, android-music-player

In my Android app I want to play or resume the played music after I pause it. I got my app to [pause the music by sending a broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129027/android-application-to-pause-resume-the-music-of-another-music-player-app), but I can't get it to play or resume the music.

Here is the code to pause:

```java
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "pause");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is what I have discovered after testing these.

I have tried and verified these commands to work just fine.

```
// pause
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "pause");
sendBroadcast(i);

// play
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "play");
sendBroadcast(i);

// next
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "next");
sendBroadcast(i);

// previous
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "previous");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Some more info about available commands:

```
public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";
public static final String CMDNAME = "command";
public static final String CMDTOGGLEPAUSE = "togglepause";
public static final String CMDSTOP = "stop";
public static final String CMDPAUSE = "pause";
public static final String CMDPLAY = "play";
public static final String CMDPREVIOUS = "previous";
public static final String CMDNEXT = "next";
```

taken from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java

Comment: these command will only work if the song is played by default music Player. otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "togglepause");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

**Update**

Try with the following action :

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand.togglepause");
i.putExtra("command", "togglepause");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything.
`i.putExtra("command", "pause");` pauses the music.
I want to resume it

Comment: if you use `togglepause` that does not pause/resume it? That's weird. I'll dig  a bit deeper and check other ways of doing it.

Comment: can "togglepause" pause and resume the music?

Comment: Use i.putExtra("command", "play"); after "pause". This will resume the music from where it was paused.