# How to stop background music playing on android using Appcelerator (Titanium)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, background-music

Can anyone help me to know how to stop the background music playing on android once I open my application in Android (I'm using Appcelerator Titanium)

Answer (score 1):

Titanium Mobile doesn't integrate Android's [Audio Focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) functionality, [as indicated by the lack of Audio Focus-related method calls](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AudioFocus&type=Code). Therefore, you aren't able to request permanent audio focus using the framework itself, which would stop audio playback from other active apps.

You can [create a Titanium Module](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Development+Guide) that implements this functionality though.

---

You may have some modest success creating intents for specific applications, for example, sending a pause intent to `com.android.music.musicservicecommand`, the default music player. See these resources:

- [android - how to play or resume music of another music player from my code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910360/how-to-play-or-resume-music-of-another-music-player-from-my-code)
- [Android Audio Focus How to » Community Questions & Answers » Appcelerator Developer Center](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/159105/android-audio-focus-how-to)