# Android - How to stop other apps playing audio?

Tags: android, audio

I need play some audio through internal speaker.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

My problem - when i do this, if another app play audio, he start playing too  through internal speaker. How i can avoid it?

I read this topic: [How to stop other apps playing music from my current activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390126/how-to-stop-other-apps-playing-music-from-my-current-activity)  but in my case i want force closing any audio playing.

Comment: why do you need to stop thea app , you can request audio focus `requestAudioFocus` before playing the audio file and then abandon the audio focus after you finish `abandonAudioFocus` and usually apps mutes the audio when they are not in focus

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop other apps playing music from my current activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390126/how-to-stop-other-apps-playing-music-from-my-current-activity)