# Detect background audio playing on Android

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` application running on both iOS and Android currently I have discovered an issue with playing sounds inside my app while there is background audio already playing. iOS was easy enough to solve by detecting the presence of `AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().OtherAudioPlaying`.

I am stumped on whether it is possible to detect if anything is already playing audio on Android. I seem to be able to discover how to play audio in the background but nothing on how to check if there is existing audio playing. Currently both the background audio and my sounds play together which can leave a rather unpleasant experience.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: check this stackoverflow answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441833/how-to-detect-an-application-is-playing-audio-or-recording

Comment: @Jason thanks. I didn't want to grab focus but your link helped me to discover the answer which I will post shortly.

Comment: @NikhilJain thanks. The second answer on that post actually looks closer to what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is pretty much as simple as the iOS approach so long as you know the right place to look :). Thanks to the commenters I found that `IsMusicActive` is available on the `Android.Media.AudioManager` class. Therefore my solution looks like:

```cs
public class AudioHelper : IAudioHelper
{
    public static void Init(Activity activity)
    {
        audioManager = (Android.Media.AudioManager)activity.GetSystemService(Activity.AudioService);
    }

    private static Android.Media.AudioManager audioManager;

    public bool IsOtherAudioPlaying => audioManager?.IsMusicActive == true;
}
```

Comment: Where did u place this code am having trouble understanding that ?

Comment: @csharpdude77 I had to place it in the Android platform specific project. Basically this but in the Android project:
https://blog.bijington.com/2021/07/22/detecting-background-audio-in-an-ios-app.html

Comment: Ah my bad am wanting my app to play in  the background