# Stoping background broadcast from another application

Tags: java, android, receiver

I have an application that launches a stream, if i turn on the music playback in any other application then it plays the two tracks in parallel. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390126/how-to-stop-other-apps-playing-music-from-my-current-activity)

Basically, you can't stop other applications from playing their audio. You can however, be alerted when another application begins playing audio, and react accordingly. All credit for this answer goes to [Pranav Jadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189222/pranav-jadav).

```
private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (focusChange) {
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                // Lower the volume while ducking.
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                pause();
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                stop();
                ComponentName component =new ComponentName(AudioPlayerActivity.this,MediaControlReceiver.class);
                am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: added listener to AudioManager and its works great.

AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusChangeListener
                , AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
                , AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

Thank You!